# SDL2 with OpenGL -- weird results, what's wrong?

Tags: opengl, sdl, macos, porting

I'm porting [an app](http://beltoforion.de/galaxy/galaxy_en.html) to iOS, and therefore need to upgrade it to SDL2 from SDL1.2 (so far I'm testing it as an on OS X desktop app only). However, when running the code with SDL2, I'm getting weird results as shown on the second image below (the first image is how it looks with SDL, correctly). The single changeset that causes this is [this one](https://r.mail.yandex.net/urls/KN__vmaM6t6WK7QGZikDJw,1350638107/github.com/ber4444/Galaxy-Renderer-on-iOS/commit/c1060971678239ea79a8a537a7e73a1089f7a272), do you see something obviously wrong there, or does SDL2 have some OpenGL nuances I'm unaware of?
My SDL is based on the latest [from HG](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/shortlog/6608).

**Update:**  another question about the iOS port of the same project [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231805/gl-arb-point-parameters-porting-to-ios).

**Update 2:** this is now also on the SDL newsgroup: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.sdl/58026

**Update 3:** I tried using [Regal](https://github.com/p3/regal) for portable OpenGL, the not-so-good result is on the third screenshot, produced merely by replacing

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

with

```
#include "GL/Regal.h"
#include "GL/RegalGLU.h"
```

[image: using SDL 1.2]
[image: using SDL 2]
[image: using Regal with SDL 2]

Comment: Is it possible that (for whatever reason) the sprites/particles are simply rotated ~90°, or stretched to very thin rectangles? A wireframe view should let you check that quickly.

Comment: According to the changeset you linked, you're rendering using glCallLists(), which is not supported under OpenGL ES (which is what you'll be using under iOS).  (I'm kind of surprised that it doesn't give you compile errors on iOS, to be honest.)

Comment: the screenshots were coming from OS X, the iOS porting came after that (an glCallLists was only used for text rendering which was linux specific so I was not using it even on OS X)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres your problem notice I comment out the surface = SDL_Get... it was giving some weird results. Also you forgot to create the OpenGL context. Let me know if you have any other issues.

```
SDLWindow::SDLWindow(int width, int height, double axisLen, const std::string &caption)
:m_fov(axisLen)
,m_width(0)
,m_height(0)
,m_fps(0)
,m_idxSnapshot(0)
,m_camPos(0, 0, 2)
,m_camLookAt(0, 0, 0)
,m_camOrient(0, 1, 0)
,surface(NULL)
,m_texStar(0)
,m_bRunning(true)
{
SDL_GLContext ctx;

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    throw std::runtime_error(SDL_GetError());
atexit(SDL_Quit);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RETAINED_BACKING, 1 ); 

 if ((window = SDL_CreateWindow(caption.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
 SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | 
 SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS)) == NULL)
    throw std::runtime_error(SDL_GetError());     

/*if ((surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)) == NULL)
    throw std::runtime_error(SDL_GetError());*/

m_width = width;
m_height = height;

ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

InitGL();
}
```